# JavaScript - how to measure execution time for each part of a code

Tags: javascript, node.js

JS code for connecting to DB and getting data is bellow.

I can run the whole code in terminal using `node db.js` command and measure total execution time but would like is to measure how long it takes for each chunk of code to execute in milliseconds:

```
# Part 1:
var mysql = require('mysql');

# Part 2:
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '...',
    user: '...',
    password: '...'
    port : ...
    database: '...'
});

# Part 3:
connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM table", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
  connection.end();
});
```

How to measure each part above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `console.time('name')` and `console.timeEnd('name')` to measure time between 2 places in your code.

would look something like this:

```
console.time('part1')   //start timer for part 1.
var mysql = require('mysql');
console.timeEnd('part1')    //end timer 1 and log how long it took.  

console.time('part2')   //start timer for part 2.
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '...',
    user: '...',
    password: '...'
    port : ...
    database: '...'
});
console.timeEnd('part2')    //end timer 2 and log how long it took. 

console.time('part3')   //start timer for part 3.
connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM table", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    console.timeEnd('part3')    //end timer 3 in the callback and log how long it took. 
  });
  connection.end();
});
```

Comment: Would that take into account asynchronous nodejs approach? (e.g. if we have `console.time('name')` and then Part 1 of the code execute asynchronously - it might just 'pass trough' and hit the next `console.timeEnd('name')` which could provide false (lower) time than what actually takes to execute Part 1, or is really waiting in sequence for Part 1 to finish)?

Comment: To do that, you would have to do the timeEnd in the asynchronous callback.

Comment: @connexo - Do you have example of `timeEnd in the asynchronous callback`?

Comment: Added an example with the timeEnd in the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Use `console.time(String str)` to start a named timer, and `console.timeEnd(String str)` to end measuring and ouput the time in the console.

```js
function countToThousand(callback) {
  console.time('part1');
  let a = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    a += i
  }
  callback(a)
}

function myCallback(a) {
  console.log('a is '+a);
  console.timeEnd('part1')
}

countToThousand(myCallback)

// etc
```

Comment: How to put a value of  `console.timeEnd('part1');` into a variable so that can be used later?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot. `timeEnd()` returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

In case your question is actually "how to know what part of code is sloooow".
Tool that makes such a thing is named "profiler".

NodeJS has integrated profiler that can be attached to your IDE(like [Inteliji Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/v8-cpu-and-memory-profiling.html))

Or you can search for dedicated package(like [v8-profiler](https://github.com/node-inspector/v8-profiler)) that connects to V8 profiler and draw charts/fill the table with some other package/your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in nodejs perf_hooks. For example:

```
// Dependencies
const { performance, PerformanceObserver } = require('perf_hooks');



performance.mark('start part1');
console.time('part1')   //start timer for part 1.
var mysql = require('mysql');
console.timeEnd('part1')    //end timer 1 and log how long it took.  
performance.mark('end part1');

performance.mark('start part2');
console.time('part2')   //start timer for part 2.
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '...',
  user: '...',
  password: '...'
    port: ...
  database: '...'
});
console.timeEnd('part2')    //end timer 2 and log how long it took. 
performance.mark('end part2');

performance.mark('start part3');
console.time('part3')   //start timer for part 3.
connection.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM table", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    console.timeEnd('part3')    //end timer 3 in the callback and log how long it took. 
    performance.mark('end part3');

    // Create observer to log out all the measurements
    const obs = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
      // called once. list contains three items
      const measurements = list.getEntriesByType('measure');
      measurements.forEach((measurement) => {
        console.log(`${measurement.name} ${measurement.duration}`);
      });
    });
    obs.observe({ entryTypes: ['measure'] });

    // Gather all the measurements
    performance.measure('Beggining to end', 'start part1', 'end part3'); // Measure whole function
    performance.measure('Part1', 'start part1', 'end part1'); // Measure the part1
    performance.measure('Part2', 'start part2', 'end part2'); // Measure the part2
    performance.measure('Part3', 'start part3', 'end part3'); // Measure the part3

  });
  connection.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this method

```
 const startTime =new Date().getTime();

//part of the code

const endTime = new Date().getTime();
console.log(`time taken=> ${(endTime - startTime)/1000} seconds`);
```